# ENOENT (No such file or directory)/File path not found

Tags: android

I have a part of an android app where the user selects a photo from their device. The code works on Android 13 but not on Android 11 or earlier.

I have tried two different versions of the getPath function but neither works on all versions

```
private fun getPathFromUri(uri:Uri) : String {
val contentResolver = applicationContext.contentResolver

        val filePathColumn = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
        var cursor: Cursor? = null

        try {
            cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null)
            cursor?.moveToFirst()

            val columnIndex = cursor?.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]) ?: -1
            return if (columnIndex != -1) {
                cursor?.getString(columnIndex) ?: ""
            } else {
                ""
            }
        } finally {
            cursor?.close()
        }
```

```
 val contentResolver = applicationContext.contentResolver

        val filePathColumn = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
        var cursor: Cursor? = null

        try {
            cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null)
            cursor?.moveToFirst()

            val columnIndex = cursor?.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]) ?: -1
            return if (columnIndex != -1) {
                cursor?.getString(columnIndex) ?: ""
            } else {
                ""
            }
        } finally {
            cursor?.close()
        }
```

This code goes with the other code

```
 private fun copyTo(source: File, destination: File) {
        source.inputStream().use { input ->
            destination.outputStream().use { output ->
                input.copyTo(output)
            }
        }
    }



private val pickMedia2 = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()) { uri ->
        if (uri != null) {
            val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
            scope.launch {
                val randomString = generateRandomString()
                Log.d("testing", randomString)

                val oldFile = File(getPathFromUri(uri))
                Log.d("testing", oldFile.isFile.toString())
                Log.d("testing", oldFile.name)
                Log.d("testing", oldFile.path)
                Log.d("testing", oldFile.absolutePath)

                val extension = "png"
                val localFileName = "${randomString}Image2.${extension}"
                val localDir = File(this@EditProfile.getExternalFilesDir(null), "images")
                if (!localDir.exists()) {
                    localDir.mkdirs()
                }
                val newFile = File(localDir, localFileName)
                copyTo(oldFile, newFile)
                val newFilePath = newFile.absolutePath
                databaseHelper.replacePhotoReference(newFilePath, 2)
                uploadFile(uri, "2")
            }

            Glide.with(this)
                .load(uri)
                .transform(MultiTransformation(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(60)))
                .into(userPhoto2)
            rotatePlusButton(2, false, fast = false)
            photoTwoSet = true
        }
    }
```

I did the testing on two physical devices (one API 33 and one API 24) and multiple virtual devices
Do I need to have additional code to support older android versions?

Comment: You should use the uri directly. Not try to get a path from it. You can do all with the uri.

Comment: `copyTo(oldFile, newFile)` Rewrite that function so you can calll it like `copyTo(uri, newFile)`.

Comment: @blackapps Going directly from the URI to the File object solved it. That was the last major issue I had to fix, thank you for your help